# How to locate and match substring of a string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string

I need JavaScript algorithm that can match substring of a sting?

```
subStringFinder('abbcdabbbbbck', 'ab')
```

should return index 0

and

`subStringFinder('abbcdabbbbbck', 'bck')` should return index 10

Could you please tell me how to write this code?

**--EDIT:**

Thanks to **@Jonathan.Brink** I wrote that code and it did the trick:

```
function subStringFinder(str, subString) {
  return str.indexOf(subString);
}

subStringFinder('abbcdabbbbbck', 'bck') // -> 10
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) function which is available via the built-in string type (as well as [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)).

Example:

```
var str = "abbcdabbbbbck";
var n = str.indexOf("bck");
// n is 9
```

Probably, rather than having a custom `subStringFinder` function it would be better to just use `indexOf`.

Comment: Thank you very much! It was so easy with this funcion.

Comment: You should not answer questions that are obvious duplicates, mark them as a duplicate instead.